# Getting all the rows of a MySQL table and putting them in a listbox

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I want to get all the rows of table of a MySQL database and store them in a listbox. I am using vb.net. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not Make-A-Wish where you spew your wants and desires and someone writes code for you.  Do some research, write some code and post a real question when you get stuck.

Comment: Cool story, bro. Thanks for the status report. Was there a *question*?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim Column0 As String

    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=catalogname; Integrated Security=True; Connection Timeout=3"

    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM MyDB"

    connection.Open()

    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, connection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read() Then
    Column0 = dr(0)
    End If

    connection.Close()
```